# Manim not drawing correctly circuits in MacOs

Tags: latex, manim

I am trying to draw the following circuit with manim on MacOs Mojave 10.14.6:

```
from manimlib.imports import *                 

class TikzMobject(TextMobject):
    CONFIG = {
        "stroke_width": 3,
        "fill_opacity": 0,
        "stroke_opacity": 1,
    }

class ExampleTikz(Scene):
    def construct(self):
        circuit = TikzMobject(r"""
            \begin{circuitikz}[american voltages]
            \draw
              (0,0) to [short, *-] (6,0)
              to [V, l_=$\mathrm{j}{\omega}_m \underline{\psi}^s_R$] (6,2) 
              to [R, l_=$R_R$] (6,4) 
              to [short, i_=$\underline{i}^s_R$] (5,4) 
              (0,0) to [open,v^>=$\underline{u}^s_s$] (0,4) 
              to [short, *- ,i=$\underline{i}^s_s$] (1,4) 
              to [R, l=$R_s$] (3,4)
              to [L, l=$L_{\sigma}$] (5,4) 
              to [short, i_=$\underline{i}^s_M$] (5,3) 
              to [L, l_=$L_M$] (5,0); 
              \end{circuitikz}
            """
            )
        self.play(Write(circuit))
        self.wait()
```

which should work fine and draw a beautiful circuit. But then the result I got  is this one : 
[image]

Does anyone know if it is only a MacOs problem or how to solve it ?

EDIT : I tried on Linux (Fedora) and it works perfectly . It must be a problem due to MacOs

Comment: Just as information: the latex part of your code works without problems.  (I know nothing about manim, so I can't comment on that)

Comment: Yes @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I know the latex code works. I only hope that someone who knows manim more than me see this post. I don't even know if it only is a MacOs problem

Comment: @Jatos, if you haven't had any luck yet, try asking on the [manim discord](https://discord.gg/mMRrZQW). Normally someone can solve your problem pretty quickly.